# Reuse OpenAPI/Swagger definition with different validation rules?

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi

Let’s say I have a REST API with a User resource. There are three methods that work with the User resource: `POST` to create, `GET` to download and `PATCH` to change. All methods operate on the same User type, but have different required properties – when creating the user using `POST`, all request fields except the user ID are mandatory, when downloading using `GET`, all response fields are mandatory including the ID, when changing using `PATCH`, all request fields are optional and nullable.

Can I succintly describe this in OpenAPI/Swagger? I would like to describe the User type just once and then only say which fields are required/nullable for each method. A bit like this, in pseudocode:

```
definitions:
  User:
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
      name:
        type: string
      …
paths:
  /users
    post:
      request:
        schema: User
        required: [name, …]
        nullable: […]
      response:
        schema: User
        required: [id, name, …]
        nullable: […]
  /users/{id}:
    get:
      response:
        schema: User
        required: [id, name, …]
        nullable: […]
    patch:
      request:
        schema: User
        required: []
        nullable: [name, …]
```

This way I would not have to repeat all the field definitions while having the particular constraints described for each method. Is that possible? Does it make sense?